# Powershell script convert excel to csv with pipe delimiter and text qualifier

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I'm trying to convert excel files (xls) to csv with pipe (|) delimiter and text qualifiers (") which is located in a folder using PowerShell.  This [post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3223/extract-and-convert-all-excel-worksheets-into-csv-files-using-powershell/) helped me with default conversion of csv file (comma separated without text qualifier)
please advise how to convert Excel to CSV with custom delimiter and text qualifiers.

Comment: Can you please post your code so we can maybe see where you are going wrong? Just a reminder that Stack overflow is not a code writing service

Comment: I don't think Excel will do that. It quotes fields where they are needed (when the delimiter character is part of the field for instance), but not all fields regardless. With PowerShell you can use [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) with the chosen delimiter character to end up with a file that has quoted fields.